# Passing parameters to server side code on a jqGrid edit row

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I am trying to use JQgrid and edit my objects. However, I don't know how to pass parameters to the server side code. Here is my jq code:

```
 jQuery("#tblList").jqGrid({
            url: 'CityList.aspx/GetList',
            editurl: 'CityList.aspx/GetList',
            mtype: 'POST',
            datatype: 'json',
            postData: { searchString: '', searchField: '', searchOper: '' },
            ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
            serializeGridData: function (postData) {
                var propertyName, propertyValue, dataToSend = {};
                for (propertyName in postData) {
                    if (postData.hasOwnProperty(propertyName)) {
                        propertyValue = postData[propertyName];
                        if ($.isFunction(propertyValue)) {
                            dataToSend[propertyName] = propertyValue();
                        } else {
                            dataToSend[propertyName] = propertyValue
                        }
                    }
                }
                return JSON.stringify(dataToSend);
            },
            jsonReader: {
                root: "d.rows",
                page: "d.page",
                total: "d.total",
                records: "d.records"
            },
            colNames: ['Id', 'Şehir Adı'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'CityId', index: 'CityId', hidden: true },
                { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 400, editable: true, edittype: 'text' }
            ],
            ondblClickRow: function (id) { alert("You double click row with id: " + id); },
            pager: '#tblPager',
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            sortname: 'CityId',
            sortorder: 'desc',
            rowNum: 10,
            loadtext: "Yukleniyor....",
            shrinkToFit: false,
            multiselect: false,
            emptyrecords: "Kayit Bulunamadi",
            autowidth: true,
            shrinkToFit: true,
            height: "400",
            rownumbers: true,
            //subGrid: true,
            caption: 'Şehirler'
        }).navGrid('#tblPager', { add: true, edit: true, del: true, reload: true });

    });
    jQuery("#tblList").editGridRow(rowid, properties);
```

I am new to jqGrid, Can you tell me how I can edit my records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set up the DataRequesting event:

in the code behind-

```
    public void JQGridVets_DataRequesting(object sender, JQGridDataRequestEventArgs e)
    {
        ObjectDataSourceVets.SelectParameters["BusID"].DefaultValue = e.ParentRowKey;
        ObjectDataSourceVets.InsertParameters["BusID"].DefaultValue = e.ParentRowKey;
    }
```

in the aspx file -

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSourceVets" runat="server" 
        SelectMethod="GetVetAll" TypeName="AHP.Data.PhoneBookRepository" 
        UpdateMethod="UpdateVet" InsertMethod="InsertVet" 
        OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}"  >
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="M" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="vetphone" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="vetemail" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Degree" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="License" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Code" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="BusID" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="oper" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="BusID" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="M" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="vetphone" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="vetemail" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Degree" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="License" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Code" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="VetID" Type="String" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

so in the InsertMethod specified in the ObjectDataSource the busid has the correct value.

This is used to add a child record from a subgrid.